# React - sending down ref as a prop not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-ref

I am using a [react-mui](https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/menus/) library in my project where I would like to implement a `MenuList` component, found under MenuList composition [here](https://v3.material-ui.com/demos/menus/). In my application though I am sending a `ref` as `prop` down to a `child component` where I have a `menu`. You can see the codesandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-v8k3u).
When I send a `ref` and a `setRef` method as `props` from a parent component like this:

```
state = {
    open: false,
    ref: React.createRef()
  };

  setRef = element => {
    this.setState({ ref: element });
  };

  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ open: !state.open }));
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MenuListComposition
        setRef={this.setRef}
        handleToggle={this.handleToggle}
        handleClose={this.handleClose}
        open={this.state.open}
        ref={this.state.ref}
      />
    );
  }
```

To a child component that has a menu button:

```
    <MenuButton
      className={classes.button}
      handleToggle={handleToggle}
      setRef={setRef}
      open={open}
      ref={ref}
   />
```

Then the Popper component which has a menu list opens at a wrong place, which you can see in the codesanbox example if you click on the `TOGGLE MENU GROW button`.

```
      <Popper open={open} anchorEl={ref} transition disablePortal>
          {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
            <Grow
              {...TransitionProps}
              id="menu-list-grow"
              style={{
                transformOrigin:
                  placement === "bottom" ? "center top" : "center bottom"
              }}
            >
              <Paper>
                <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
                  <MenuList>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
                  </MenuList>
                </ClickAwayListener>
              </Paper>
            </Grow>
          )}
        </Popper>
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this, or how can I use `ref` in a `stateless` component where I would avoid sending down `ref` as a `prop`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ref` is a keyword in reactjs. When you use `ref` as a prop it linked the component to the ref object. Rename it to whatever you like on `FancyButton` component and `MenuListComposition` component.

From [react documentation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs)

> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any component.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-67ygo) with ref renamed to parentRef in both components.

**EDIT:**

As pointed it out by Vaibhav Shukla, you can use `React.forwardRef` on both `FancyButton` and `MenuListComposition` which is probably the correct way to do this.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2t7rs)

Comment: Your example shows the same bug as mine. The menu list is opening below the first button and not the last one as it should.

Comment: Try it again maybe I did some tests that interfered with yours.

Comment: Thanks, man. I wasted more than 2 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 6):

Ref cannot be passed like a prop in React. Refs are commonly assigned to an instance property when a component is constructed so they can be referenced throughout the component. Moreover, When a ref is passed to an element in render, a reference to the node becomes accessible at the current attribute of the ref.

React provides method **React.forwardRef** to pass refs in the component hierarchy. This is typically not necessary for most components in the application. However, it can be useful for some kinds of components, especially in reusable component libraries. [Read about forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref)

```
    const ButtonWrapper = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <button ref={ref}>
        {props.children}
      </button>
    ));

    // You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
    const ref = React.createRef();
    <ButtonWrapper ref={ref}>Click me!</ButtonWrapper>;
```

Comment: It works, but annoyingly creates console log warnings in development `Warning: [object Object]: 'ref' is not a prop.`, which pollutes the test console