# forwardRef resulting in null for ref.current in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a parent component `LoggedInHome` and a child component `MainInput` on it. From `LoggedInHome`, I want the ability to focus on a `TextInput` within `MainInput`. From `MainInput` I want to be able to clear `TextInput`. Here's my setup:

`LoggedInHome` (parent):

```
export function LoggedInHome({ navigation }) {
    const ref_input = useRef();
    function focusInput() {
        ref_input.current?.focus()
    }
    [More logic, including a call to focusInput - this does NOT work]
    return (
        ...
        <MainInput navigation={navigation} ref_input={ref_input} />
    )
}
```

`MainInput`:

```
const MainInput = forwardRef(function MainInput({ navigation }, ref_input) {

    let swipeableRow: Swipeable;
    
    const updateRef = (ref: Swipeable) => {
        swipeableRow = ref;
    };

    [Logic where I call swipeableRow.close() - this works]
    [Logic where I call ref_input?.current?.clear() - this does NOT work]

    return (
        <Swipeable
            ...
            ref={updateRef}
            ...
        >
            <View>
            <TextInput
                ...
                ref={ref_input}
                ...
            />
            </View>
        </Swipeable>
    );
```

I set this up trying to follow the [forwardRef](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/forwardRef#usage) documentation closely, but none of the uses of `ref_input` are working as expected. While debugging, I noticed that in the child, `ref_input` is null so `ref_input?.current` is null, while in the parent, `ref_input` is just `{current: null}`.

What am I misunderstanding in how forwarded refs work?

Comment: What does the code for the `TextInput` component look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947196/react-sending-down-ref-as-a-prop-not-working
check 
ref_input={ref_input} />
ref={ref_input} />

Comment: refs are super weird because there are many ways to handle them, I asked this over 2 years ago and it still helps me a lot to this day. Of course, I try not to use refs if I can help it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488719/how-to-use-forwardref-with-functioncomponent-in-react-native-using-typescript

Comment: Thanks for sharing your previous question! Useful explanation. I think I managed to figure out how to get my problem solved, which surprisingly means not using forwardRef at all - the whole experience has been confusing, so glad to read that I'm not the only one who finds refs confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Made a couple of changes which in combination seem to have worked.

The first is following [this article](https://itnext.io/reusing-the-ref-from-forwardref-with-react-hooks-4ce9df693dd), which is a solution for the need for both the parent and the child to use refs in the child. Turns out you have to declare a ref in the child and explicitly combine the ref from the parent and the ref from the child.

That alone didn't solve the issue. The second thing, surprisingly, was to not use `forwardRef`. The parent component code stayed the same from what I had above. The child component now takes `ref_input` as a part of the props. So in short, the start of the child component code looks like:

```
export function MainInput ({ navigation, ref_input }) {
    const innerRef = React.useRef(null)

    const combinedRef = useCombinedRefs(ref_input, innerRef)
    ...
```